# SQL Server - DECLARE @name TYPE --##TempGlobalTable

Tags: sql-server, global, declare, temp

Here is the specific query I am having trouble with.

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME --##DATE

If I ran it without `--##DATE`, the query returns no results. I understand `--` is a comment and `##` is a global temp table. But why wouldn't it work? Even taking the `--` out, the query doesn't return any results.

The fact I've declared a `DATETIME` datatype should be enough surely?

I am using T-SQL through a finance application where you can create your own views.

Comment: Are you claiming that just `DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME` (without anything before or after it) results in an error? Which one?

Comment: Tag the DBMS you're using.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a good description of a problem - what happens? Do you get an error? If so, what error? If not, what were you *expecting* it to do and what is it doing differently. We're good problem solvers, not mind readers

Comment: The problem is most likely in your "finance application" - which you did not tag. Since a true view cannot contain parameters or local variables, that suggests that the term "view" has a specific meaning to this application as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

In my mind, this code obviously works:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
```

However, it does *nothing* that is apparent so by itself it is hard to diagnose (without an explicit error).  Hence, to know whether such code is working or not working you probably have code afterwards.

My suspicion is that the following code is causing the error *because the `DECLARE` does not have an explicit statement delimiter (better known as a *semicolon*).

In such a scenario, the comment is providing enough information to the parser to prevent the error.  However, it would be better to just write:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME;
```

I can't think of a way of reproducing this problem.  But you can see the importance of statement terminators with code like:

```
declare @x int;
(select 1)
```

Remove the semicolon and you will get an error